# Exits on a highway are numbered consecutively from 1 to 50, find the maximum possible distance between exit 47 and 48.

Tags: number-theory

Exits on a highway are numbered consecutively from 1 to 50. The distance from exit 41 to exit 50 is 100 km. If each exit is at least 6 km from the next exit, what is the longest possible distance, in kilometers, between exit 47 and exit 48?

---

Since there are 9 "spaces" between all the exits, there must be a minimum of $54$ kilometers. Adding all the remaining distance (46 kilometers) to the "space" between exits 47 and 48, we have our answer as $6+46=52$ kilometers.

---

I am probably making a really simple mistake here but I can't figure it out. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you're making a silly mistake. Does it disagree with the "official" answer or something else like that? As far as I can tell, your solution is correct.

If you wish to double-check your answer, consider more explicitly stating the distances between each exit. For example, for the $8$ other distances, with $0 \le i \le 8$, except for $i = 6$, going from stop $41 + i$ to $41 + i + 1$ is at least $6$ km., so it can be expressed as a distance of $6 + e_i$ km., where $e_i \ge 0$. This gives a total # of km. of $\sum_{i=0,i \neq 6}^{8}(6 + e_i) = 48 + \sum_{i=0,i \neq 6}^{8}e_i$. The remaining distance in km. for between exits $47$ and $48$ would be $100 - (48 + \sum_{i=0,i \neq 6}^{8}e_i) = 52 - \sum_{i=0,i \neq 6}^{8}e_i$. Since $e_i \ge 0$, the maximum value would be when you have all $e_i = 0$, which gives a result of $52$ km.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misread the solution. They also said that the answer is 52 km, but I was reading their "bogus solution" where they stated a wrong answer which many people might accidentally use to solve the problem. Sorry!

Comment: @RobertBrown then you should accept the answer.+1

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot.